# Good way to proceed with development of event management system using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-design

I want to know how to develop an event management system. I want to use your [RESTfull service using codeigniter](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver).

I am not sure how to proceed with that. currently am planing to follow below steps.

1. Design and Develop the UI for the application
2. Design the MySQL database
3. Start coding the back end using codeigniter
4. Develop the API

Is that a good way to do that, I have to do it solo.

What will be your workflow for below application

1. Event Management system which can support multiple event
2. Attendee registration with steps to choose hotel booking and exhibitions and finally payment.
3. All data will be available in back end app.
4. API interface to event website, which will show the registration form and speakers etc. Data will be fetched from the mail API.

and more...

Please tell me how I can proceed with that.

**Do you create UML diagrams for that. please write the steps. and how much time it will take if you develop same.**

Thanks

Comment: "how much time it will take if you develop same" - This is impossible to answer for your specific scenario and, as such, isn't a good fit for [SO's Q&A format](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). I suggest reading over the FAQ's to help you formulate a question that is both practical and answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be:

1. Design the UI in Twitter Bootstrap.
2. Draw UML and Database Diagrams to clear much confusions.
3. Code the Backend using CodeIgniter.
   3.1 Spend time on the two sides of your system, Event Creator and Event Attendee.

Although, I'd prefer Rails for such apps. My two cents of advice.

Comment: Thanks Ali, how much time it will take to develop it.

Comment: It can take around 800 hours, also can you upvote thanks.

Comment: i'm 1400 hours in on a similar application. using CI..